# Selenium driver is not reflecting updates after click on link

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

There are some posts about this topic but I cannot find any solution for my case, this is the situation:

I click on a link (a next page):

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(next_el).click().perform()
```

Then I get the content of the new page(I'm interested on some script sections inside the body)

```
html = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*").get_attribute("outerHTML")
```

But that content is always the same, **no matter how long I wait for.**

The only way to get the driver with new DOM information is to do a refresh(),
but for this case that is not a valid option.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for here, but if I am right you want to capture the content of script tag from the page.
If that is the case capture the page source in a string variable 
sorce_code = driver.page_source , after you get the sting you can extract the value by any of the available string methods. I hope it helps.

Comment: In fact I do that, extract the information that is inside the script tag parse it and use it, the problem as I said is: after doing that and clicking in the next page link the driver.page_source is not updated, so the content is the same than in the previous page. Since I red that driver.page_source is not a stable description of the dom that's why I use the find_element, but having the same result the driver content is not updated, I don't understand why. The only way to make the driver to update the doom is to do a driver.refresh() but that's not valid in my case.

Comment: Can you try adding a explicit wait for the title of the next page and put sufficient time that you feel it might be taking for the page to load

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I din't try the explicit wait, but I used a time.sleep() for more than enought time, after that, reading the driver.page_source still has the same information than in the previous page...